# Looking for easier solutions to simple problem

Tags: python, function

I am new to Python and currently taking a course online. This was one of the problems given to me on an assignment. It looks like I've solved it correctly but looking at my code, it looks pretty complicated. I was wondering what other ways there were to solve this problem so I can learn better. Thank you.

**The problem was :**

Write a Python function to check whether a string is pangram or not. (Assume the string passed in does not have any punctuation)

Note : Pangrams are words or sentences containing every letter of the alphabet at least once.
For example : "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"

**ispangram("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog")**

**Answer :**

```
import string

space = ""

def ispangram(str1, alphabet=string.ascii_lowercase):
    str1 = sorted(str1.replace(" ", "").lower())
    if set(space.join(str1)) == set(string.ascii_lowercase):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 1):

You convert this to a function, this uses a generator expression and using ASCII codes:

```
s = "A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
print(all(chr(x).lower() in s for x in range(65,91)))
```

The boolean value will indicate if all characters are present or not. A function for this:

```
def ispangram(s):
  return all(chr(x).lower() in s for x in range(65,91))
```

It will first iterate over range 65 to 91 and then convert them to their characters from ascii code and check if it is in s, and combine all 26 conditions with `all()` like an AND. And return the result.

Comment: Should strip spaces. Since this was a question by a person in a course, you might explain why it works. But it should work

Answer (score 0):

Assuming English character set, this can be done with the following steps:

- lowercase the string since case is irrelevant here.
- make a list out of only the alpha characters in it;
- make a set out of that to remove duplicates;
- make sure the set has all possible letters.

In terms of code, a succinct version of that follows (with text above incorporated to make it clear to future developers how it works):

```
# Returns true if and only if the given sentence
# contains all English letters at least once:
#   1. Lowercase sentence.
#   2. Make list from letters in sentence.
#   3. Make set from list to remove duplicates.
#   4. Ensure set has exactly 26 letters.

def isPangram(sentence):
    return len(set([letter for letter in sentence.lower() if letter.isalpha()])) == 26
```